# Fetch image server side with php without CURL and ftp_get

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I've an IP-associated ftp access to an host, say ftp.host.com and I need to show in php pages (hosted somewhere else) some images hosted on the ftp site

The website php pages are the only ones allowed to access ftp.host.com because of the IP policies.

Of course, if I call images with " the call is done by the client, not the server, so it fails because of IP policies.

How can I call the images from server side? I can't use CURL nor FTP_GET because of the well known ftp over NAT php bug described here:

http://www.elitehosts.com/blog/php-ftp-passive-ftp-server-behind-nat-nightmare/

And I can't patch php because it's on an hosted server so I'm out of ideas

Any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

These might work for you [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

```
$remoteImage = "http://www.example.com/gifs/logo.gif";
$imginfo = getimagesize($remoteImage);
header("Content-type: $imginfo['mime']");
readfile($remoteImage);
```

Comment: thanks but no, I tried it already but it fails just like ftp_get, curl, get_file_contents etc, all because (I suppose) the php bug I linked.